# how can I call/import a pre-trained model (neural network) in python to Matlab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Please, I've trained a U-net model using Fastai library and I'd like to call the trained model from Matlab. Please, is there any way to do so?

Your help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not an easy task in most cases, you can try using [mcnPyTorch](https://github.com/albanie/mcnPyTorch) or [onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials)

Comment: I have the same question. Do you have results already?